# Error converting Pandas Dataframe to Spark Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I basically have a data frame with two columns. It currently is a Spark data frame and looks like this.

```
recommender_sdf.show(5,truncate=False)
+------+-------------------------+
|TRANS |ITEM                     |
+------+-------------------------+
|163589|How to Motivate Employees|
|373053|How to Motivate Employees|
|280169|How to Motivate Employees|
|495281|How to Motivate Employees|
|3498  |How to Motivate Employees|
+------+-------------------------+
```

Basically two columns with first column TRANS standing for ID of an individual and ITEM is the name of item video he watched.

I wanted to cross-tab this dataset such that each item the individual watched would appear as separate column with the total count of that as value for that column.

I first tried using Spark data frame Cross-Tab function but it showed the following Java Heap error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o72.crosstab.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericMutableRow.<init>(rows.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.stat.StatFunctions$$anonfun$4.apply(StatFunctions.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.stat.StatFunctions$$anonfun$4.apply(StatFunctions.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:224)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.stat.StatFunctions$.crossTabulate(StatFunctions.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions.crosstab(DataFrameStatFunctions.scala:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I didn't understand this error, so I thought of converting the Spark data frame to Pandas Dataframe and use Pandas Cross tab function to cross tab and then convert back to Spark Dataframe.

While Pandas cross tab works fine and it cross tabs the dataset. However now when I try to convert it into Spark Dataframe using createDataframe function it is throwing the following error:

```
# Creating a new pandas dataframe for cross-tab
​
recommender_pct=pd.crosstab(recommender_pdf['TRANS'], recommender_pdf['ITEM'])

Converting the pandas Dataframe back to Spark Dataframe
In [31]:

# Creating a new Spark dataframe for cross-tab from Pandas data frame

recommender_sct=sqlContext.createDataFrame(recommender_pct)
```

---

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-234fe3fbf3e5> in <module>()
      1 # Creating a new dataframe for cross-tab
----> 2 recommender_sct=sqlContext.createDataFrame(recommender_pct)

/Users/i854319/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.pyc in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio)
    423             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data, schema, samplingRatio)
    424         else:
--> 425             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(data, schema)
    426         jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
    427         jdf = self._ssql_ctx.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())

/Users/i854319/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.pyc in _createFromLocal(self, data, schema)
    331         if has_pandas and isinstance(data, pandas.DataFrame):
    332             if schema is None:
--> 333                 schema = [str(x) for x in data.columns]
    334             data = [r.tolist() for r in data.to_records(index=False)]
    335 

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u201c' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any help on this please?

Comment: May I suggest you to write the panda in a file (csv, parquet) and try to read it using Spark?

Comment: Yes, or to quit Spark and move to Dask

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Quick questions: 

1) Any idea why I get the error for Spark Cross-tab function as mentioned above? 

2) Writing to file from pandas and then importing that file is an issue in Pandas to Spark (I was able to import other pandas df correctly) or something specific to this problem?

Comment: Hi The spark Csv package is not working on my spark. Could you help in how to convert the pandas data frame to another format which Spark can read? Would really appreciate